Why does this inverse limit of compact spaces not equal the union?
Let $Q= \{q_1,q_2,\ldots\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$. Define $X_0 = [0,1] \times \{0\}$ and for each $n > 0$ consider the compact connected space $$X_n = \big([0,1] \times \{0\}\big) \cup \big( Q_n \times [0,1]\big)$$ where $Q_n = \{q_1, \dots, q_n\}$. This space is obtained by attaching vertical segments to the first $n$ rational points in $[0,1]$.
This gives an increasing chain $X_0 \subset X_1 \subset \ldots$ of compact connected spaces. There are obvious continuous retractions in the other direction $f_{n+1}: X_{n+1} \to X_n$ that squash each $\{q_{n+1}\} \times [0,1]$ to the point $(q_{n+1},0)$ and leave the other points fixed. It is straightforward to check commutativity of the diagram:
$$ \ldots \xrightarrow{f_3} X_2 \xrightarrow{f_2} X_1 \xrightarrow{f_1} X_0.$$
Hence the inverse limit $$L = \left \{(x_i) \in \prod_i X_i : f_{i+1}(x_{i+1}) = x_i \ \forall i=0,1,2,\ldots\right\}$$of the system is defined.
The inverse limit contains the union $\bigcup_i X_i$ in an obvious way. For each $z \in X_n$ let $x_n = z$. This determines $x_{n-1}, x_{n-2}, \ldots, x_0$. Since each $f^m_n = f_m \circ f_{m-1} \circ \ldots \circ f_{n+1}$ is a retraction we can just select $x_m = x$.
Here is the problem $-$ the inverse limit of compact spaces is known to be compact. So we cannot have just $L = \bigcup_i X_i$ as the union
$$ \bigcup_i X_i = \big([0,1] \times \{0\}\big) \cup \big( Q \times [0,1]\big)$$
is certainly not compact. Despite this, I cannot for the life of me find any other nontrivial points of the inverse limit.
Can anyone help?

I am not very well-versed with those kind of things. Have you checked whether the topology induced by the inverse limit coincides with the subspace topology?

"It is straightforward to check commutativity of the diagram" - what has to be checked here?

I am not 100% sure what the question is. Do you want to calculate $L$? Do you want to only show that $L$ is not the union (as in the title)? But you already proved that? Also, what do you mean with "nontrivial points"?

@MartinBrandenburg I think the point is whether $L$ differs from the union (which would require first proving that the topology induced by the inverse limit coincides with the subspace topology). If it is indeed the subspace topology, then the question would be what one gets on top of the union and whether one can get explicit examples of such points.

@MartinBrandenburg I am wondering whether $L$ differs from the union, in terms of either the base set or the topology. Nontrivial points would be points in the limit that are not in the union.

You have already proven that $L$ is not the union. I assume your real question is to find a specific point of $L$ that is not in the union? That should be very easy, just using that the $f_n$ are surjective.

@MartinBrandenburg You keep insisting that it is already shown that $L$ is different from the union. Does that mean it is easy to see that the topology induced by the inverse limit coincides with the subspace topology?

Let $X = X_0 \cup Q \times I$. Clearly $X = \bigcup_n X_n$. You say that $L$ contains $X$ in an obvious way, but this is misleading because it suggests that $X$ can be regarded as a subspace of $L$. This is not true , but we shall construct a canonical injection of sets $\phi : X \to L$.
Let $\mu_i : X_i \to X_{i+1}$ denote inclusion. We have $f_i \circ \mu_i = id$.
For $j \ge i$ let $f^j_i = f_{i+1} \circ \ldots \circ f_j : X_j \to X_i$ be the composed retraction and let $\mu^j_i = \mu_i \circ \ldots \circ \mu_{j-1}: X_i \to X_j$ be the composed inclusion. Clearly $f^j_i \circ \mu^j_i = id$ and $f^i_i = \mu^i_i = id$.
Define
$$\phi_n : X_n \to L, \phi_n(x)_i = \begin{cases} \mu^i_n(x) = x  \in X_i & i  \ge n \\ f^n_i(x) \in X_i & i \le n \end{cases}$$
Clearly $\phi_n$ is an injection.
We claim that $\phi_{n+1} \mid_{X_n} = \phi_n$. So let $x \in X_n \subset X_{n+1}$. For $i \ge n+1$ we have $\phi_{n+1}(x) = \mu^i_{n+1}(x) = \mu^i_{n+1}(\mu_n(x)) = \mu^i_n(x) = \phi_n(x)$. For $i \le n$ we have $\phi_{n+1}(x) = f^{n+1}_i(x) = f^{n+1}_i(\mu_n(x)) = f^n_i(x) = \phi_n(x)$.
Therefore the $\phi_n$ can be pasted to $\phi : X \to L$ such that $\phi \mid_{X_n} = \phi_n$. This function is an injection: Consider $x,y \in X$ such that $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$. There exists $n$ with $x,y \in X_n$. Then $\phi_n(x) = \phi_n(y)$, thus $x = y$.
We shall prove that $\phi$ is surjective. Consider $(x_i) \in L$.
Case 1. All $x_i \in X_0$.
For $i > 0$ we have $f_i(x_i) = x_i$ because $X_0 \subset X_{i-1}$. But $f_i(x_i) = x_{i-1}$ since $(x_i) \in L$, thus $x_i = x_{i-1}$ for all $i > 0$. We conclude $x_i = x_0$ for all $i$. But then $(x_i) = \phi_0(x_0) = \phi(x_0)$.
Case 2. Some $x_i \notin X_0$.
So let $x_n \in X_n$ with $x_n \notin X_0$. In that case $x_n$ is the only element of $X_{n+1}$ which is mapped by $f_{n+1}$ to $x_n$ (recall that the only nontrivial fiber of $f_{n+1}$ is $f_{n+1}^{-1}(q_{n+1},0) = \{q_{n+1}\} \times I$ and that $(q_{n+1},0) \in X_0$). This shows that $x_i = x_n$ for $i \ge n$. Therefore $(x_i) = \phi_n(x_n) = \phi(x_n)$.
Summarizing, $\phi : X \to L$ is a bijection. It cannot be a homeomorphism because $X$ is non-compact and $L$ is compact.
Actually it is easy to see that $\phi$ is not continuous. If it were, then  $\pi_1 \circ \phi : X \to X_1$ would be continuous, where $\pi_1 : L \to X_1$ is the projection to the first coordinate. By construction of $\phi$, the function $\pi_1 \circ \phi$ maps all $\{q_k\}  \times I$ with $k > 1$ to $(q_k, 0)$. Since $Q$ is dense in $I$ and $\pi_1 \circ \phi  \mid_{\{q_1\}  \times I} = id$, we get a contradiction.
